# Load wrong photos from Firebase when fill collectionView cells image not happen everytime

Tags: firebase, swift3, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to know if it's an issue with my code because almost half time the images load from Firebase (which are an URL in Firebase) doesn't display the right photo from Firebase.
I show you two screenshots from my collectionView:
- First one this case are the right photos loaded: (there's no error in this case), this is what I want to display everytime

[image]

- Second one, if I reloaded the view I can see this image, in this case you can see two photos are in double, but the right photos should be like in the first image (Firebase doesn't load the right images from Storage)

[image]

If I reload again this issue can appear again or show the right photos in the right place.
So I don't know why this issue.

Here's you can see my code for the cellRowItemAt function of collectionView :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    let photoLive = liveRecent[indexPath.row].photoURL

    self.storageRef.reference(forURL: photoLive!).getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (imgData, error) in
        if let error = error {
            let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alertView.show()
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if let data = imgData {
                    cell.imageViewUn.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            })
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.imageViewUn.reloadInputViews()
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

What's wrong with my code?
Thanks for any help.

Edit: What should I write in the prepareForReuse() function:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageViewUn: UIImageView!
var downloadTask: StorageDownloadTask!

public override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.imageViewUn.image = nil

    downloadTask.cancel()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely occurs because the setting of the image in your collection view cell is decoupled from the lifetime of that cell. When you set the image in the cell you don't know if that cell is still valid or if it has been reused for another cell. You need to either be able to cancel your image load when the cell is reused or store in your cell the cell index and once the image is loaded check if the index has changed.

A useful function you can use to catch when a cell is reused is

```
UICollectionReusable.prepareForReuse().
```

Override this in your cell class and add in code to cancel your image load or somehow invalidate it.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try that. Do you think there's the same function for UITableView? Because I think I will need the same thing for tableView

Comment: UITableViewCell has a prepareForReuse() function

Comment: What should I write in the prepareForReuse() function in my cell class for cancel the load image or invalidate it? Because I try "isHidden" property but same issue. Can you provide me some tips please ?

Comment: I updated my answer with my custom class but there's a fatal error because I remove the imageView from superview so maybe I should readied it when I reload my images function? How to do that

Comment: I guess if you keep a handle to your storage download task in the cell you can cancel the download in prepareForReuse(). I don't have a great deal of experience with Firebase so can't be sure. Don't remove the UIImageView

Comment: Ok I don't remove from superview and just and just set nil to the image of the imageView but same issue so I search for a cancel function of Firebase but fatal error (see my edited post)